# Remove the previous click from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 5 dt tag with different id with span tag. Every span tag has a same image. 
For example:

I have a save icon under each dt. When user click on it - it change to non-save icon.

Now if i am on first dt and click save icon it was change to non-save thats perfectly fine.when i go to second dt and click it save icon it was change to non-save icon that it also ok but i need to remove the non-save icon in first dt and change to save icon.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: How about posting some code or setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your code looks like but maybe the following will help you:
HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr id="buttons">
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.safe {
  background: url(../safe.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.non-safe {
  background: url(../unsafe.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons").getElementsByTagName("td"),
    i = 0,
    len = buttons.length;

for ( ; i < len; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var button = buttons[i];
      if (button === this) { this.className = "safe";
      } else { button.className = "non-safe"; }
    }
  }, false);
}
```

You could also google for "event delegation" for a more advanced technique:

add a listener to the common ancestor element of the td elements instead of adding one listener each.